# Finding the LastRow in multiple column ranges?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I'm trying to find the LastRow in multiple column ranges ignoring certain columns... I have two attempts but can't get either working correctly:

#### BOTH Examples are ignoring columns N and O

My first attempt is the following, however it doesn't get the correct last range, if I have something in A15 for example and T10, it thinks the last row is 10 when it should be 15.

```
Sub LastRowMacro()
    LastRowString = "A1:M" & Rows.Count & ", P1:Z" & Rows.Count
    LastRowTest = Range(LastRowString).Find(What:="*", After:=[A1], SearchOrder:=xlByRows, searchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
End Sub
```

My second attempt is as follows, but it seems rather long winded.

```
Sub LastRowMacro()

    Dim i As Long

    LastRow = 1
    IgnoreColumnList = "N;O"

    For i = 1 To Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        ColumnLetter = Split(Cells(1, i).Address(True, False), "$")(0)
        For Each varFind In Split(IgnoreColumnList, ";")
            If varFind = ColumnLetter Then
                varNotFound = False
                Exit For
            End If
            varNotFound = True
        Next
        If varNotFound Then
            CurrentLastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, i).End(xlUp).Row
            If CurrentLastRow >= LastRow Then
                LastRow = CurrentLastRow
            End If
            varNotFound = False
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Ideally I'd like my first attempt to work however if it just doesn't work then someone surely can improve my second version...

Comment: I am a bit confused. Can you show a sample screenshot and better explain the expected results? It sounds like you're trying to find the last row in between columns A to M and then P to Z and compare which one is greater.

Comment: I'm trying to get the lastrow A to M and P to Z, thus ignoring columns N and O. The second script works how it should just it's not as fast as it could be. My actual sheet has over 150 columns and 70 of them need to be ignored.

Comment: are those 70 that youre ignoring consecutive?

Comment: @mehow Nope, they are completely split up in various places, my IgnoreColumn list looks similar to: "F;H;J;N;O;Q;S;T;U;Z;AB;AD;AE;AR" and it goes on, the easiest way I've found is to just use this way.

Comment: ok try the code from my answer and please let us know if it improved the speed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

*There is an `ignoreList` variable with all the columns that you want to ignore. Make sure you populate this correctly - *currently ignoring `N`, `O`, `P`*

*You may need to set the `sh` variable to the correct sheet - *currently it's `Sheet1`*

*btw. this snippet will always find the **last** last row on the spreadsheet. you can add another `elseif` to check whether there are 2 columns with the same high last row in case there was 2 columns with the highest lastRows.

```
Sub FindingLastRow() ' ignoring some columns

    Dim ignoreList
    ignoreList = Array("N", "O", "P")             ' MODIFY IGNORE LIST

    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Set sh = Sheet1                               ' SET CORRECT SHEET

    Dim currentlast As Range
    Set currentlast = sh.Cells(1, 1)
    Dim iteratingCell As Range

    With sh
        For j = 1 To .UsedRange.Columns.Count
            Set iteratingCell = .Cells(1, j)
            If Not isIgnored(iteratingCell, ignoreList) Then
                If iteratingCell.Cells(Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row >= currentlast.Cells(Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row Then
                    Set currentlast = iteratingCell
                End If
            End If
        Next
    Set currentlast = .Range("$" & Split(currentlast.Address, "$")(1) & "$" & currentlast.Cells(Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
    End With

    MsgBox currentlast.Address

End Sub

Function isIgnored(currentlast As Range, ignoreList As Variant) As Boolean
    Dim ignore As Boolean
    Dim letter As Variant
    For Each letter In ignoreList
        If StrComp(Split(currentlast.Address, "$")(1), letter, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
            ignore = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    isIgnored = ignore
End Function
```